# Firebase storage Quota has been exceeded

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have set up a test account on firebase just for development purposes.

I made use of the storage feature and so I uploaded manually an image with the size of 400kb which later I downloaded through an IOS application.

All of a sudden the application stopped working and I cannot access the storage from the console.. I get the message "warning Can't connect to server. Try again in a few minutes."

By searching in the stackoverflow, I found some people claiming that this has to do with multiple google accounts signed in from the same browser etc..

The IOS application though, logs the following error:

> Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={object=images/nicewall.jpg, bucket=partyreports-49b0a.appspot.com, ResponseBody={
>     "error": {
>       "code": 402,
>       "message": "Quota has been exceeded for this project. Please visit the Firebase pricing page to learn more."
>     }

Please pay attention to the message "Quota has been exceeded.."

How is this even possible? The analytics/events shows "session_start:193" which I assume is how many times the application connected to the Firebase.

Now if my calculations are correct 193x400KB is way less than the 30GB traffic limit..

It is worth noting that I have a second project setup under the same account which I don't use at all.. and the storage is accessible..

After googling a bit, I found that I should have billing information setup.. and so I did.. after a few minutes I can access the storage again..

How can I tell what was wrong?

- Was it the billing account? Or that was a random incident?
- I do NOT believe my app exceeded the limits
- How often the limits reset?
- Where can I see the actual limits for each service/feature?

Thanks and sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sorry you had issues! Here are some answers:

- Was it the billing account? Or that was a random incident?

Unsure why it happened--it's possible that there's a bug in our quota system, or it's possible that you ended up storing or sending more data than you thought. I'm not sure how you're using storage, but if you've got a 400kB image and we have a 1GB/day limit, that's 2500 downloads/day. If you've got 200 users, and they use the app routinely, and the file is downloaded on app start every time, that might explain extra usage.

Our free plan offers 30GB outgoing bandwidth per month, 5GB of data storage total , and 20,000 uploads and 50,000 downloads operations per day--once these limits are hit, the app won't work until the quota resets, or until you upgrade your app. Once you upgrade, the quota limit is removed and the app works, which is why your problem went away.

- How often the limits reset?

The bandwidth is 30GB/month, enforced as a daily limit (so every 24 hour period means you're allotted 1GB of bandwidth). This limit resets every day.

Storage is 5GB total, and once exceeded you need to remove additional data  (or upgrade your plan) before the app works again.

Operations are 50,000 downloads and 20,000 uploads per day.

See the [quota limit docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket) for more info.

- Where can I see the actual limits for each service/feature?

We're working on exposing usage data for each service in their respective sections of the Firebase Console. Stay tuned for more on this.

Comment: wonderful feedback.  However,  once the storage quota is exceeded firebase just shows an error and you can't delete the files.  How does one delete files from firebase storage after exceeding the quota on a free account without adding payment details?

Comment: @Mike McDonald why you are not able to see your uploaded images if you exceed your limit? That is absolutely absurd.

Comment: @Mike McDonald have the same issue, I have 2 images uploaded about 1-2 mb in size, and I am using the app only myself, actually I was doing the ios codelab for friendlychat and it started to give this error at the 10th step. It is quite impossible for me to go over the quotas all by myself I guess :/

Comment: I assume this is you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/i_U2KzuQm2U ? It's actually very possible for people to go over these limits (1GB download per day), since people are bad as estimating file sizes. The iOS standard images are ~20MB in size as well, which doesn't make the situation any better.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald "Quota for bucket myapp.appspot.com exceeded, please view quota on firebase.google.com" same issue as user above. 1 image (200kb) uploaded. called it about 20 times in the last hour and now this message? very weird o.0

Comment: @MikeMcDonald additionally.. it is not possible to delete any images or even see the filelist. no chance to make room for new images, which is not necessary in our cases, i think

Comment: @alexdd55 mind reaching out via https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ so you can give me project name info which I can use to check it out?

Comment: For those we are still confused about the quota of the app, you may head to this link to view the quota of your current app

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails

The limit of 1GB transfer/day is super likely to reach.

Comment: it's 2020, i don't think there is a simple way to see what quota's were exceeded. how about a quota dashboard?

Comment: A couple top comments complain that you can't delete files once you've reached your storage quota. As of now, if you're at quota due to storage size (10GB) this would be helpful to be able to do. However, you're probably at quota due to data transfer (360 MB/day), so having access to this would be informative, but not solve the problem immediately, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

I had te same issue,
I had upgraded it to blaze plan and then deleted some of the data from the storage and then again downgrade the plan to free and it will start working for testing

Answer (score 0):

firebase limits the number of new Email/Password and Anonymous accounts that your application can create in a day from a single IP address.

you can [check this out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits?authuser=0&hl=en#sign-ups) to change and schedule sign up quota.

Found this in firebase project authentication settings.

Answer (score 0):

For future ref please use cached_network_image and for videos cached_video_player cause believe it or not i just blew through the 1GB limit withing an hour testing the video player using a stored 1mb video. The band with is a problem amongst other things on firebase so cache where you can and if you cant i suggest you find other file hosting services