# Firebase storage quota exceeded?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have been developing an application using firebase storage, I am currently using the free plan, yesterday I was testing and I noticed that on my firebase storage I gt the error

> You have exceeded your quota for this project. Please upgrade your plan.

I am really confused as to how this could have happened. I am definitely not exceeding the limit my images sizes are really small and I am the only one accessing the files at the moment.

I came on stackoverflow to find answers to the problems. It seems this user had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361517/firebase-storage-quota-has-been-exceeded), just that my application is on android. I am getting concerned with this now because I do not understand how this is possible and am considering moving over to AWS if this persists because it does not allow me to continue development.

I am using the glide function to pull images from storage into my recycler view. The images are max 5mb and there are not many of them.

Can a firebase dev possibly give me the breakdown of my usage if I provide my details? Maybe somewhere I can email to? And does anyone else have this problem?

thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that the quota is enforced daily, so 1GB/day. See Mike's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361517/firebase-storage-quota-has-been-exceeded

Comment: I face same problem ..but i think i exceed my 1GB file transfer limit per day

Answer (score 1):

Firebase storage has a limitation for free usage which is 5GB storage and 1GB transfer daily you must pay to upgrade your limit you can check thier website https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

You must have exceeded it or someone purposely throttled your bandwidth.

Show us the report of traffic and we'll calculate the math for you.