# Firebase's Cloud Firestore Free Quota Run Out Permanently Once Exceeded?

Tags: android, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have read about the pricing for Firebase's Cloud Firestore usage and in the first screenshot below it says:

> Quotas are applied daily and reset around midnight Pacific time.

While in the second screenshot it says:

> After you exceed the usage and storage quotas for the free tier,
>   you're charged for the database operations you perform

**My Concerns:**

Let's say I build an app using Firebase's Cloud Firestore and at some point the app exceeds the free quota:

1. Will that free quota be permanently gone (never to be accessed again) after exceeding it for the first time.
2. Will I now be automatically charged after exceeding the free quota? (even though I have never signed up for billing)

**Or**

1. Since I am using the **free tier quota** and haven't signed up for billing, I'll just be restricted from communicating with the backend until I stop exceeding the free quota limits?
2. Will the free quota still reset at midnight as long as I make sure to stop exceeding the free quota limits?

Essentially, I have never signed up for a billing account, I have always had a free Firebase account, **so what precisely happens** when a **free account** user exceeds the free quota provided by Cloud Firestore?

**1st Screenshot:**

[image]

**2nd Screenshot:**

[image]

**Additionally:**

Is it more feasible to build a social media app (with lots of read and writes to and from the backend), such as when users' make posts in the app, with **Cloud Firestore** or should I use the classic **Real Time Firebase Database**? **(In terms of pricing)**

**Lastly:**

It was stated on Firebase that users can monitor their quotas using App Engine. My concern is, in order to use this, do I have to be using a paid billing account or can a free account user monitor his/her quotas if using the app engine?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was stated on Firebase that users can monitor their quotas using App Engine. My concern is, in order to use this, do I have to be using a paid billing account or can a free account user monitor his/her quotas if using the app engine?

I'm using the free plan, haven't set up a paid billing account, yet I can see the usage at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails

[image: Firestore usage]

Comment: You have answered only one of the OP's questions?

Answer (score 5):

A good answer is available here: [Firebase storage Quota has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361517/firebase-storage-quota-has-been-exceeded)

Résumé: your app won't work until (1) quota are (automatically) reset, or (2) you upgrade to the paid account.

Btw, note that each document in a query counts as a read, and the quota are determined among other thanks to the number of reads. Think to cache data, using Android `preferences` in the app you develop, for example.

So, only based on my understanding of the quoted above answer:

> Will that free quota be permanently gone (never to be accessed again) after exceeding it for the first time.

No

> Will I now be automatically charged after exceeding the free quota? (even though I have never signed up for billing)

No

> Since I am using the free tier quota and haven't signed up for billing, I'll just be restricted from communicating with the backend until I stop exceeding the free quota limits?

Yes

> Will the free quota still reset at midnight as long as I make sure to stop exceeding the free quota limits?

Didn't really understand ; your free quota will be reset automatically at a given horodata (normally explained in the Google documentation of Firebase/Firestore).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't know the exact answer to your question, I do know how you can find out... test your questions. It sounds like you don't want to risk burning all your free quota from your existing account, but there is nothing to prevent you from creating another account and testing with that.

Also worth remembering that as a cloud based solution, what is true today may not be true tomorrow.

Regarding RealtimeDB vs Firestore in terms of pricing...
I think this will be very difficult for someone else to answer - in terms of pricing. The [data structure in RTDB vs Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) are very different so the storage, bandwidth, reads and writes that you would make in each DB would be different.

For example; in RTDB you use flat data structures so you need to make extra reads for each piece of related data. If you have lots of relational data this might not suit. Firestore allows nested data, so you can fetch related data with single reads, but you'll get repetition of data so you'll need more storage. 
Its a trade-off that should be investigated per application. Again, there is nothing to stop you trying both RTDB and Firestore with different logins, so you can compare usage. Remember to Structure your data differently to suit each DB's and see which one lets you access the data in the most efficient way.

Finally, as of today, Firestore is still in Beta. I think this is Googles way of telling you to be cautious. The systems is ready for testing and examples, but production data might not be 100% safe.