# Firebase storage states full after deleting all files

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

[image]
Like many other people out there, I am using Firebase for my project. In the past few days I have used Firebase quite a lot for sending media files between users. Now, I am also on the free plan, as I am still testing Firebase. 
All of a sudden, Firebase has stopped responding, mentioning that

```
"You have exceeded your quota for this project. Please upgrade your plan.
    LEARN MORE"
```

I know that Firebase has a limit on the amount of data I can transfer per day and store, that's no problem. My problem is that even after a full day, and having everything in storage deleted, I still get the same error.

Truth is, this error only shows up for the storage section. But, as you can see in the picture, my storage is now empty. Therefore my question is how can I reset firebase, or there's no other way around other than paying?
Since I am not able to see any files, I am also suspecting that I have not deleted them all, or them correctly? Could this be what's going on?

The more interesting part is the when clicking on `"LEARN MORE"`, I am prompted to the following page, which is even more misleading.
[image]

**Update:** After looking at my [quota details](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails) I found out that my Cloud Storage Network is full:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Pricing for Storage on the Spark Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) it says that you can store up to 5Gb of data. Now this plan is based on Cloud Platform's Always Free and [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) says "5Gb-months". I'm not sure of what that means, but I'm assuming that you have already exceeded your 5Gb for this month (even though you deleted the files afterwards). Maybe your [quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails) will actually have some kind of "refresh" next month so you'll probably only be able to use Firebase storage again by that time.

Comment: This could also be a bug, so I'd recommend that you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) and/or [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/)

Comment: Also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38389410/5861618)

Comment: what's interesting is that the quota has yet to be lifted to this date, which also leads me into thinking that it's a bug. On the other hand, could it be that I have not properly deleted all data? I mean the storage does say it's 0, but maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: I don't think it could be about data not properly deleted.

Comment: If you [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) they'll be able to have a deeper look into your project and tell you what's going on and how to proceed.

Comment: aparently my "Cloud Storage Network (Egress) - Americas and EMEA" is full. I'll attach a screenshot. The thing is, I don't know how do delete the files from this storage. I don't even know how they got there in the first place. My firebase storage still shows empty.